# Rails 3: Many to many relationship with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I have 2 models e.g task model and task_relation model
Task has many parent tasks and child tasks.

Have added following associations -

**Task.rb**

```
  has_many :from_tasks, :as => :relation, :class_name => "TaskRelation", 
                        :foreign_key => "task_from_id", :source => :parent, 
                        :conditions => {:relation_type => 'Parent'}, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :to_tasks , :as => :relation, :class_name => "TaskRelation", 
                       :foreign_key => "task_to_id", :source => :child, 
                       :conditions => {:relation_type => 'Child'}, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :child_tasks, :through => :from_tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :parent_tasks, :through => :to_tasks, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :to_tasks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :from_tasks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

**TaskRelation.rb**

```
  belongs_to :parent_task, :class_name => "Task",  :foreign_key => "task_from_id"
  belongs_to :child_task, :class_name => "Task", :foreign_key => "task_to_id"
  belongs_to :relation, :polymorphic => true
```

When I save task form, it also saves parent_tasks and child tasks in task_relations table with relation_type as 'Task' but I want to store relation_type as 'Parent' for parent tasks and 'Child' for child tasks.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: This model looks needlessly complex - can you clarify (in words, not code) precisely what a task needs to be associated with?

Comment: Want to associate task model with task as parent task and child task. Need to store this association in task_relation model as which task is  parent task and which is child task.

Comment: Are there expected to be more than one parent and child per task?

Comment: Yes...task can have multiple parent tasks and multiple child tasks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the `relation` polymorphic association - it's not needed.  Now, modify your `Task` model to look like this:

```
# This association relates to tasks that are parents of self
has_many :parent_task_relations, class_name: 'TaskRelation', foreign_key: 'child_task_id'
# And this association relates to tasks that are children of self
has_many :child_task_relations, class_name: 'TaskRelation', foreign_key: 'parent_task_id'

has_many :child_tasks, :through => :child_task_relations
has_many :parent_tasks, :through => :parent_task_relations
```

And you should be done.

To illustrate how this might be used - say you have a Task `a` and need to assign task `B` as a parent, and task `C` as a child.  You could accomplish this like so:

```
a.parent_tasks << b
a.child_tasks << c
```

This would have the same effect on your database as this code:

```
a.parent_task_relations.create(parent_task: b)
a.child_task_relations.create(child_task: c)
```

Which is the same (to the database) as:

```
TaskRelation.create(parent_task: b, child_task: a)
TaskRelation.create(parent_task: a, child_task: c)
```

Comment: I have added this relation earlier...but according to its use in the application, I need to modify to different between parent and child task with original task.

Comment: For.eg. If there are 3 tasks A, B and C and I associate B as parent task to A and C as child task to A. And there can be many. So inorder to differentiate who is parent and who is child. I need this polymorphic association.

Comment: No, you don't.  In the example you gave, you can simply create 2 TaskRelations, one with "parent: B, child: A", and one with "parent: A, child: C".  In the first relation, A will be detected as the child, and in the second A will be detected as the parent.

Comment: Extending to this relation, I need to share file with parent and child task means Task A can share file with Task B and Task C And multiple parent or child tasks. There I cannot find who has shared file to whom  using task_relations table without any polymorphic association.

Comment: @SaileeReddy: Polymorphic associations are meant to be used where multiple model classes need to associate with a common model. Since you are (until this point) only connecting Task models (A, B, & C), there is no reason for this to be polymorphic - it can be a standard belongs_to *_id field.  Secondly, is there any real connection between B and C in the example given?  Perhaps an update to your question with a broader explanation of what you want to accomplish would go a long way to clarifying this...